# Microsoft Teams alternative with ability to deploy your own independent server

Tags: chat, screen-sharing, voice

Are there any free/open source alternatives to Microsoft Teams with text/voice channels, group video calls + screen sharing, file sharing features etc.? But it should be able to be deployed on an independent server on your own machine or cloud.

Answer (score 1):

You could go with **[Nextcloud](https://apps.nextcloud.com/)**, which you can deploy onto your own servers.

- **file sharing:** provided out-of-the-box. You can share to other members of your own instance, to Email-addresses or even anonymously, including password protection if needed.
- **ext/voice channels, group video calls + screen sharing**  are provided by the **[Nextcloud Talk](https://apps.nextcloud.com/apps/spreed) app.

Nextcloud is open source and comes fee of charge. Like *Nextcloud Talk,* there are [many more apps](https://apps.nextcloud.com/) to extend the functionality. On a side note: the German government decided for Nextcloud for their [Bundescloud](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundescloud), which strongly speaks for its maturity.

[image]
[image]
<sup>*Nextcloud* (source: [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nextcloud)) and *Nextcloud Talk* (source: [Nextcloud](https://apps.nextcloud.com/)); click images for larger variants</sup>

What you didn't ask for: there are also several apps for mobile devices, to keep data synchronized with your Nextcloud or have a "native app" for e.g. Talk – though you could use all of it simply via your web browser.